# Redirecting with <rewrite> in web.config not redirecting

Tags: c#, .net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I wrote a rule but its not working.

I need to redirect `testsite` with `articles` to `about-park/blog`.

```
  <rule name="Redirect Articles" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="articles" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testsite.co.uk$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/about-park/blog/" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
```

If the url is `https://www.testsite.co.uk/articles/testpage` then it should redirect to `https://www.testsite.co.uk/about-park/blog/testpage`

Similarly, `https://www.testsite.co.uk/articles/1/testing` to `https://www.testsite.co.uk/about-park/blog/1/testing`

Comment: is your redirect working if you remove conditions?

Comment: nope it doesn't work @AliReza

Comment: so probably your problem is not related to the rules. check your web.config format and iis modules

Comment: try with this pattern `/testsite.co.uk/`

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: @AliReza what needs to be checked in web.config and IIS?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed there are two possible problems. either your configuration is wrong or the IIS URL Rewrite module not working at all. you can try a simple rule to find out. for example, redirect everything `(.*)` to some static URL (action part). if it worked you can try to find a good match pattern. 
Personally, I always use `(.*)`, and later I limit it with some conditions ...

Comment: Use FRT to learn what's behind the scene, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and also study some basic regular expressions (as you wrote wrong patterns).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Rewrite feature.

e.g

```xml
<rule name="Articles">
    <match url="^(.*)/articles/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/about-park/blog/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

note: just change Rewrite to Redirect in action type if you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you can refer to my redirect rule sample below:

```
<rule name="Articles">
    <match url="^articles/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.testsite.co.uk$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/about-park/blog/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Please note, there are some improvement compared with the solution provided by AliReza. First, if we add `/` before `articles/(.*)`, it can not match the rule. Second, If the request url is `https://www.testsite.co.uk/abc/articles/testpage`, it will be redirect to `https://www.testsite.co.uk/abc/about-park/blog/testpage` if use his redirect rule sample.